# dockerized nginx "times out" after several minutes

Tags: nginx, docker

I have nginx running in a docker container using the stock nginx image.  It is proxying to gunicorn running a django app.

5 seconds after the last connection, I see a number of "client 172.18.64.88 closed keepalive connection".  Then, if I wait 5 minutes or more, the first attempted connection errors out on the client end.  If I immediately hit the "Try Again" button that Firefox defaults to with connection issues, it will then connect.

I'm currently using docker 1.90rc1 with nginx 1.9.5

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.9.5
built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-threads --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-http_v2_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed' --with-ipv6
```

I also experience a lot of docker hangs.  Docker will frequently hang up for several minutes or longer to the point where I have to reboot the box.  Not entirely sure how to debug that at present.

Following is the inspect for the nginx container:

```
[
{
    "Id": "01ceb09884dae63e13e663d43e6b35115c23cae0e02a4bff8c75e039971f6a5f",
    "Created": "2015-10-28T16:25:52.885407197Z",
    "Path": "nginx",
    "Args": [
        "-g",
        "daemon off;"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 19594,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2015-10-28T16:25:55.559977049Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "5c82215b03d10884d98e0c074a69881e7428484c47855d49863233297f86fd9a",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "EndpointID": "",
        "SandboxID": "7a4a6f275d49f438f4e3cffbce72328bab65f22dc5648e430b93c83e24a60489",
        "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
        "Networks": [
            "bridge"
        ],
        "Ports": {
            "443/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "443"
                }
            ],
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7a4a6f275d49",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null
    },
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/01ceb09884dae63e13e663d43e6b35115c23cae0e02a4bff8c75e039971f6a5f/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/01ceb09884dae63e13e663d43e6b35115c23cae0e02a4bff8c75e039971f6a5f/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/01ceb09884dae63e13e663d43e6b35115c23cae0e02a4bff8c75e039971f6a5f/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/01ceb09884dae63e13e663d43e6b35115c23cae0e02a4bff8c75e039971f6a5f/01ceb09884dae63e13e663d43e6b35115c23cae0e02a4bff8c75e039971f6a5f-json.log",
    "Name": "/docker_nginx_1",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "btrfs",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/usr/local/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro",
            "/usr/local/docker/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx/log:rw",
            "/usr/local/docker/nginx/ssl:/nginx/ssl:ro",
            "/usr/local/docker/virtualenvs/lss/src/cisco/static:/static:ro",
            "/usr/local/docker/virtualenvs/lss/src/cisco/media:/media:rw"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": null,
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {
            "443/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "443"
                }
            ],
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Links": [
            "/docker_web_1:/docker_nginx_1/docker_web_1",
            "/docker_web_1:/docker_nginx_1/web",
            "/docker_web_1:/docker_nginx_1/web_1"
        ],
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": [],
        "VolumesFrom": [],
        "Devices": null,
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "VolumeDriver": ""
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "btrfs",
        "Data": null
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Name": "1492af30f865754d65f67357d67e9d6b039df0be0c905c3387bca7e0e28fd47a",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/1492af30f865754d65f67357d67e9d6b039df0be0c905c3387bca7e0e28fd47a/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/cache/nginx",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true
        },
        {
            "Source": "/usr/local/docker/nginx/nginx.conf",
            "Destination": "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false
        },
        {
            "Source": "/usr/local/docker/nginx/logs",
            "Destination": "/var/log/nginx/log",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true
        },
        {
            "Source": "/usr/local/docker/nginx/ssl",
            "Destination": "/nginx/ssl",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false
        },
        {
            "Source": "/usr/local/docker/virtualenvs/lss/src/cisco/static",
            "Destination": "/static",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false
        },
        {
            "Source": "/usr/local/docker/virtualenvs/lss/src/cisco/media",
            "Destination": "/media",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "01ceb09884da",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "443/tcp": {},
            "80/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "VIRTUAL_HOST=pttlvl1",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "NGINX_VERSION=1.9.5-1~jessie"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "nginx",
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "Image": "nginx",
        "Volumes": {
            "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": {},
            "/media": {},
            "/nginx/ssl": {},
            "/static": {},
            "/var/cache/nginx": {},
            "/var/log/nginx/log": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "f1ce82828ce42bdf943575acbf5ac7cb9b46607c0202d0d49008928766b671e9",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "nginx",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.5.0rc1"
        }
    }
}
]
```